# From puppeteer get a real element from a document with all its properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, dom, puppeteer

**Expected result:** I need to get an element `#app` with its `__vue__` property

**Actual result** i am getting undefined from the `data` const

**Note** If i return `document.querySelector('#app')` i get some result - undefined.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com/'); // url for example
  const functionToInject =  function(){
    return document.querySelector('#app').__vue__.$root.$options._base;
  }

  const data = await page.evaluate(functionToInject);

  console.log(data)
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Are you sure the `#app` element is on the page when that function executes? Try adding `await page.waitForSelector('#app');` after `page.goto...`

Comment: yes i added waitForSelector('#app') and get some result